# ASP : trigger action server-side and return

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to do some upload post-processing.

The user upload a .zip with a lot of images (usually between 100 and 500).
I need to process that zip file to extract,modify and store images.

My problem is that this postprocessing is a bit long so the user get an HTTP error 500 because the time allocated to process the request is over.

The actual process :

1. User upload the zip file
2. Once the server has the file, process every images
3. **wait** and return an HTTP 200

I would like to have an asynchronous postprocessing :

1. User upload the zip file
2. Once the server has the file, trigger the postprocessing asynchronous method
3. **don't wait** and return an HTTP 200

Is it possible ? 
Is there a better way of doing it ?

NB: No code because that's just a question about architecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just execute your post-processing in another thread.

You may use

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{ 
   /*your post-processing code*/ 
   //...etc
   /*when finished, notify user that post-processing has finished, maybe by email*/
});
```

It is much better not to make all requests create new threads. This will be very bad in case with a lot of concurrent users. But instead to create a single "worker" thread that executes "queued tasks" one by one.

So you can:

```
private class ProcessItem
{
   //define each task data
}

private static readonly ConcurrentQueue<ProcessItem> queue 
                                      = new ConcurrentQueue<ProcessItem>();

private static Thread worker = new Thread(() =>
{
    while (true) // infinite
    {
        ProcessItem item;
        if (!queue.TryDequeue(out item))
        { //no availble items, wait for an item
           Monitor.Enter(queue); Monitor.Wait(queue); Monitor.Exit(queue);
          continue; //I have been notified, repeat check
        }
        //now process item
    }
});

static YourClass()
{
     worker.Start(); //start the worker at class first-load
}
```

To add items to queue:

```
queue.Enqueue(item);
Monitor.Enter(queue); 
Monitor.PulseAll(queue); //notifiy the waiting threads
Monitor.Exit(queue);
```

Comment: but the parent thread won't exist anymore when this thread will need to end. I thought it was a problem, doesn't it ?

Comment: The parent thread will continue and will not wait for this code to finish. You can put "finishing" code after post-processing at the end of your thread code

Comment: So this thread won't try to notify its parent thread this it has finish his work ?

Comment: I'm gonna try and get back to you

Comment: No. The parent thread will continue execution in parallel with this thread execution.

Comment: Yeah but when the parent thread return HTTP200, his job is done and it is  destroyed (I believe)

Comment: In this case no, returning `HTTP 200` does not mean THE JOB IS FINISHED 100%. But means "the process is accepted and under execution"

Comment: Thanks for your edit. If I don't want to allocate a thread full-time for this job, I can remove the infinite loop and create the Thread if needed or queue work ? for eg with `while(!queue.TryDequeu(out item))`, right ?

Comment: Apolo No, `(!queue.TryDequeu(out item))` will stop working when no item available in queue, and will not work again when queue is having some items. Putting the thread in waiting state is better approach, which gives CPU rest because thread is in waiting-state.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think the best way would be to use Async, because you will possibly be borrowing a thread from the main threadpool, which means your server has less threads available to process other requests. Now imagine within in 1-2 secs you have 20 zip files uploaded you will be borrowing 20 or even more threads from the threadpool to process your zip file, which means in that time your server can process 20 fewer requests.

The best way for doing this would be to kick off a completely seperate **Background** process/App. For example you might.

1. User upload the zip file.
2. Save the file to some location and return from your web app with 200 ok.
3. Your web app writes and instruction i.e. some sort of record to adataabase or a file somewhere, containing the instructions on how to process the zip file.
4. some sort of app for example an exe can read these instructions and process the zip file and write the status back to database or something.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: This does not need to be an app/process. Just an infinite-loop thread can do the job. This is consumer-producer threading relationship. The website generates "queue" items, and the inifinite-loop thread processes each item in queue (or waits if no items in queue).

Comment: but you still borrowing a thread to do file processing from the same threadpool as your asp.net app

Comment: you mean like a batch process ? How can I trigger its execution ?
I have very few upload (internal tool), max 10 per week so I can allocate a thread on request

Comment: @Apolo It is much better not to make all requests create new threads. This will be very bad in case with a lot of concurrent users. But instead to create a single "worker" thread that executes "queued tasks" one by one.

Comment: @Apolo, yes exactly like a batch process, to trigger, if you are using a db you can get the batch process to watch a row in database or something for example create a method in batch process like - CheckIfThereAreAnyZipFilesToProcess, that returns a bool. if there are any then Process them. The benefit with this approach is separation of concerns, you can Develop/update and optimise your web app and batch process separately. So if lets say you have a bug in batch process you do not need to change-build and re-deploy your web app. Even use different technologies etc. etc.